# Matlab non-linear ODEs system returns [empty sym]

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve this set of equations in matlab

```
syms x(t) y(t) z(t) g m h p wz wx wy

Dx=diff(x)
Dy=diff(y)
Dz=diff(z)
D2x=diff(x,2)
D2y=diff(y,2)
D2z=diff(z,2)
eq1=diff(x,2)==(-h*sqrt(diff(x).^2+diff(y).^2+diff(z).^2)*diff(x)+p*       (wy.*diff(z)-wz*diff(y)))/m
eq2=diff(y,2)==(-h*sqrt(diff(x).^2+diff(y).^2+diff(z).^2)*diff(y)+p*(wz.*diff(x)-wx*diff(z)))/m
eq3=diff(z,2)==(-m*g-h*sqrt(diff(x).^2+diff(y).^2+diff(z).^2)*diff(z)+p*(wx.*diff(y)-wy*diff(x)))/m


g=9.81
m=2.5*10^-3
h=7.3*10^-4
p=1.8^-5
wz=-20*2*pi
wx=0.2*pi
wy=-20*2*pi
c1=x(0)==-0.5
c2=y(0)==-0.5
c3=z(0)==0.3
c4=Dx(0)==8
c5=Dy(0)==2
c6=Dz(0)==3
S=dsolve(eq1, eq2, eq3,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,t)
xSol(t)=S*x
ySol(t)=S*y
zSol(t)=S*z
```

but I get this

```
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
> In dsolve (line 201)
  In Trajectoire (line 31) 

S =

[ empty sym ]
```

I searched a solution on the forum but nothing really helps.
Can you help me to find out what the problem is  ?

Here's my trial with ode45

```
g=9.81
m=2.5*10^-3
h=7.3*10^-4
p=1.8^-5
wz=-20*2*pi
wx=0.2*pi
wy=-20*2*pi

syms x(t) y(t) z(t)

V=odeToVectorField(diff(x,2)==(-   h*sqrt(diff(x).^2+diff(y).^2+diff(z).^2)*diff(x)+p*(wy.*diff(z)-wz*diff(y)))/m,    diff(y,2)==(-h*sqrt(diff(x).^2+diff(y).^2+diff(z).^2)*diff(y)+p*(wz.*diff(x)-wx*diff(z)))/m,diff(z,2)==(-m*g- h*sqrt(diff(x).^2+diff(y).^2+diff(z).^2)*diff(z)+p*(wx.*diff(y)-wy*diff(x)))/m)
M = matlabFunction(V,'vars', {'t','Y'})

[t,x,y,z]=ode45(M,[0 100],[8 2 3])
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that an `Explicit solution could not be found.` If you are sure you implemented all equations correctly, it might simply be that there is no solution.

Comment: Nonlinear ODE systems may not have explicit analytical solutions. Try numerical integration with `ode45`.

Comment: I'm sure that there's a solution they are tennis ball's trajectory

Comment: I'm trying with ode 45

Comment: It doesn't work with ode 45 too

Comment: @gxxx Can you update your question with your code for using `ode45`?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Since your system has second-order derivatives, `odeToVectorField` will create a first-order system with six entries: three for the functions and three for their derivatives.  You need to specify the initial slope from the initial derivative conditions of your problem for `ode45` to run.

Comment: Ah okay it works thanks everyone